# In matplotlib, how can I adjust the font size and weight of a tick label using a stylesheet?

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-stylesheet

I recently started experimenting with a stylesheet (.mplstyle) for my graphs. I found examples for altering the font globally,specifically for the labels and for titles:

```
axes.labelweight: bold
axes.titleweight: bold
font.size: 12
```

However, in the documentation I can't seem to find a way to adjust the ticklabel font, font-size and/or weight. Note that the syntax is different for stylesheets (.mplstyle) than doing it right in the code (for example, using rcParams doesn't seem to work).

I tried the following already but got a "Bad key" error:

```
Axes.set_yticklabels: fontdict:{'fontsize': 8,
 'fontweight': rcParams['axes.titleweight'],
 'verticalalignment': 'baseline',
 'horizontalalignment': loc}
```

[image: Screenshot of graph with tick, ticklabel and axislabel annotated]

Answer (score 2):

Very late answer here, but I found your post while trying to figure the same thing out. You've probably figured it out, but I thought I would comment so others that find this post find the answer.

You simply set:

```
xtick.labelsize     : 10
ytick.labelsize     : 10
```

If you want a fontsize of 10 for instance.

Answer (score 0):

from [The default matplotlibrc file](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/customizing.html#customizing-with-style-sheets):

```
ytick.labelsize:     medium  # font size of the tick labels: small, medium, large
xtick.labelsize:     medium  # font size of the tick labels: small, medium, large
```